# SIGCONT on working on parent process as expected

Tags: c, signals

I need the parent process to stop till the child process sends the wake up signal to it. Only after getting the wake up signal from the child process, the parent process needs to continue the rest of the code.

I have done the following but the parent process just displays printf statement and does not take input. Please note that my input is a string. Not sure why the parent process does not take any input nor displays the final printf. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <unistd.h>     // for fork
#include<sys/wait.h>    // for wait
#include <signal.h>     // for sa_handler

#define SIZE 100    // maximum characters allowed in the chat

int main(){

    char ptr[100] = "\0";
    
    pid_t pid = fork(); // fork a processes

    if(pid < 0){
        perror("Fork #1 failed..\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid > 0){  // Parent Process
        raise(SIGSTOP);
        printf("Please enter message...\n");
        
        fgets(ptr, SIZE, stdin);
        
        printf("Parent Message: \033[0;31m%s\n", ptr);      // RED color font
    }
    else {          // Child A
        sleep(2);           
        kill(getppid(), SIGCONT);   
            
        exit(0);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side suggestion: You should change the declaration of `ptr` to `char ptr[SIZE] = "\0";` for consistency.  Also, you don't need the `\0`.  Just `= "";` will suffice.

Comment: Works fine on my Linux VM (though I have to type `fg` after running the program).  Are you only seeing the first `printf`?

Comment: Parent process just awakes up, displays the 1st printf message and then does nothing. To rerun the program, I had to kill the parent process as I see two ,./a.out on ps command.

Comment: Try running the program as follows: `./my_program; fg`.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, all I see is just 1st printf. As soon as I do any scanf or fgets, I do not see any printfs after that.

Comment: Okay, after doing fg, it works. But I would like to know why is that the case? Because I need to implement a apart of bigger project on similar idea and its very important for me to understand the reason. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

When you raise `SIGSTOP`, the control of the terminal gets returned to your shell and so any input you type will go to the shell.  Therefore, your original process is hanging with the `fgets` call.

You can verify this by running `fg` in your shell.  That will foreground the backgrounded process and you can then enter the input.

Without knowing the bigger picture of what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to provide a suggestion.  In my opinion, signals are not an ideal IPC (interprocess communication) method.  I like to use `pipe` for related process synchronization.  That is, you create a pipe, call `fork`, have each process close the appropriate end, and then the "signaling" process closes the write end when it wants to signal the other process.  The other process meanwhile calls `poll`/`select` on the read end so that it knows when the write end gets closed.

Comment: I tried to do system ("fg") on the parent (as well as child part, separately), but I could not get it work without manually doing fg on the shell. My task requires me to stop the parent process till it receives the CONT signal from the child and then continue the rest of the program that takes several prints and scanfs. Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use signals?

Comment: Yes, there are several child processes and to coordinate among them I have used signals. Is there any solution without/without using signal. I am open for any way out. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried pipes (see the last paragraph of my answer)?